# Convert Bytes to MB in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Background: I wish to convert bytes to MB using SQL Server.

This is what I am doing:

```
(CONVERT([int], ROUND([Free space bytes] / ((1024) * (1024)), (0))))
```

I would like to know if this looks correct, as it is returning results, however, I wish to see if this is the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Does it give you the correct results?

Comment: Ok yes it is giving a result here. I just want to make sure its the most efficient way to do this calculation in SQL server as well.

Comment: What is the datatype of `[Free space bytes]`?

Comment: Why? Is it causing performance issues?

Comment: I am just a bit newer to SQL and wanted some input. I will go with this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression computes the MB by dividing the input value by `1024 * 1024`: this part is correct, although you have unneeded parentheses:

```
[Free space bytes] / 1024 / 1024
```

Assuming that the column is of `int` datatype, this gives you an integer value: the decimal part is just truncated, so there is no need to `round()` and `convert()` to `int`.

On the other hand if the column is decimal, or if you want to actually round the results to the closest integer, then:

```
convert(int, round([Free space bytes] / 1024.0 / 1024, 0))
```

The `.0` at the end of the first divisor forces decimal context, if the column is `int` to start with.